# Multilevel telegram menu bot java

Tags: java, telegram-bot

I want to make that when you click on a button in the menu, new buttons (submenu) appear. I can't release it. What I tried didn't help. I'll attach the code below.

```
public void setButtons(SendMessage sendMessage){
    // Создаем клавиуатуру
    ReplyKeyboardMarkup replyKeyboardMarkup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
    sendMessage.setReplyMarkup(replyKeyboardMarkup);
    replyKeyboardMarkup.setSelective(true);
    replyKeyboardMarkup.setResizeKeyboard(true);
    replyKeyboardMarkup.setOneTimeKeyboard(false);
    // Создаем список строк клавиатуры
    List<KeyboardRow> keyboard = new ArrayList<>();
    // Первая строчка клавиатуры
    KeyboardRow keyboardFirstRow = new KeyboardRow();
    // Добавляем кнопки в первую строчку клавиатуры
    keyboardFirstRow.add("Кнопка 1");
    keyboardFirstRow.add("Кнопка 2");
    // Добавляем все строчки клавиатуры в список
    keyboard.add(keyboardFirstRow);
    // и устанваливаем этот список нашей клавиатуре
    replyKeyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboard);

    if(sendMessage.equals("Кнопка 1")){
        keyboard.clear();
        keyboardFirstRow.clear();
        keyboardFirstRow.add("Новая кмд 2");
        keyboard.add(keyboardFirstRow);
        replyKeyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work the way you want it to. You need to add callback data to each button. You can use something like that.

First of all, you need a handler with a method where you will process callback data. This can be a void or SendMessage method. This example is a bad practice. Do not use if-else.

```
private void callbackController(Update update) {
    CallbackQuery callbackQuery = update.getCallbackQuery();
    String data = callbackQuery.getData();
    if (data.contains("prev_page")) {
        execute(createEditMessageReplyMarkup(update, createKeyboard1()));
    } else if (data.contains("next_page")) {
        execute(createEditMessageReplyMarkup(update, createKeyboard2()));
    }
}

private EditMessageReplyMarkup createEditMessageReplyMarkup(Update update, InlineKeyboardMarkup replyMarkup) {
    EditMessageReplyMarkup editMessageReplyMarkup = new EditMessageReplyMarkup();
    editMessageReplyMarkup.setReplyMarkup(replyMarkup);
    // ...
    return editMessageReplyMarkup;
}
```

Then you need methods where you will create keyboards.

```
// Main keyboard
private InlineKeyboardMarkup createKeyboard1() {
    InlineKeyboardMarkup keyboardMarkup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();
    List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> keyboard = new ArrayList<>();
    List<InlineKeyboardButton> row = new ArrayList<>();
    row.add(createButtonWithCallbackData("Button #1", "next_page"));
    keyboard.add(row);
    inlineKeyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboard);
}

// New keyboard
private InlineKeyboardMarkup createKeyboard2() {
    InlineKeyboardMarkup keyboardMarkup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();
    List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> keyboard = new ArrayList<>();
    List<InlineKeyboardButton> row = new ArrayList<>();
    row.add(createButtonWithCallbackData("Button #2", "prev_page"));
    keyboard.add(row);
    inlineKeyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboard);
}

private static InlineKeyboardButton createButtonWithCallbackData(String text, String callbackData) {
    InlineKeyboardButton button = new InlineKeyboardButton();
    button.setText(text);
    button.setCallbackData(callbackData);
    return button;
}
```

Look at [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup).